# Android application based on PHP site

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to provide android app for user and admin side in PHP with MySQL database. How can I develop such project? I know PHP, but I don't know how to integrate Android App with PHP site. Can anyone recommend any online tutorial or any reference book?

Thanks in advance always helpful community :)

Comment: Will you be more specific please, because the question covers very broad area of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Create an android application. Write this code to send data to the server:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

> 2. Add this to get response from the server:

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
wr.write( data ); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

> 3. Create a PHP Script on the server:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","username","password","database name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM table1 where Username='$username' and Password='$password'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Try, visiting few tutorials [Link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm), [Link 2](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html) and then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Can you suggest some books on Android programming and Android + PHP programming.

Comment: Books would be: Android Application Development All-in-one for Dummies, Professional Android 2 Application Development. There is a channel on youtube as thebewboston, refer that for android tutorial. The OS version is old in that tutorial, but will be very fruitful.